# Save/Create MMS in inbox Android

Tags: android, mms

I am working on an Application which needs to be able to Save/Create a new MMS in inbox or Sent folders but I cant figure out the way.

I tried the following code but it gave me exception:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
values.put("body", "body 3");
values.put("read", "0");
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://mms/inbox"), values);
```

And the Exception is:

```
ERROR/Database(118): Error inserting read=0 body=body 3 msg_box=1 date=1306153444 address=xxxxxxxxxxx
ERROR/Database(118): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table pdu has no column named body: , while compiling: INSERT INTO pdu(read, body, msg_box, date, address) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
ERROR/Database(118):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
ERROR/Database(118):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
ERROR/Database(118):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
ERROR/Database(118):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
ERROR/Database(118):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
ERROR/Database(118):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
ERROR/Database(118):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1536)
ERROR/Database(118):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
ERROR/Database(118):     at com.android.providers.telephony.MmsProvider.insert(MmsProvider.java:347)
ERROR/Database(118):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:174)
ERROR/Database(118):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:146)
ERROR/Database(118):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
ERROR/Database(118):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
ERROR/MmsProvider(118): MmsProvider.insert: failed! read=0 body=body 3 msg_box=1 date=1306153444 address=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

**UDPATE:** Exception removed by removing the line: `values.put("body","body 3")` But I can't see any mms in messages.

Comment: Exception Removed by removing the line: values.put("body","body 3"); But cant see any mms in messages. and what to do to insert any Picture Or Video????

Comment: For Sending MMS via intent you can use the folllowing link : http://androiddevcentral.com/source-code/137/send-an-MMS-via-Intents

Comment: Well, thanx Kartik but i want to save/create in my inbox or sent folder. @All, guys come on, not a single answer.. :(

Comment: Ive read somewhere, that an mms can be related to a specific application... i guess that you need to set some kind of id to put your sms in the inbox folder, since by default, your creating an sms that is assigned to your specific app, and hence, will not show up in the overall mms inbox. If i find concrete info, i'll create an answer. Hope this points you in the right direction...

Comment: @Farhan, did you get your answer? I am also looking for same answer without any luck :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same problem. However I successfully created and restored an MMS. It's basically reverse manipulation of database. I hope you can get an MMS from the database, right? You just need to put back appropriate values in database tables. You can get information about database tables in mmssms.db. Once you understand the mmssms.db, it's very easy to insert an MMS.

Answer (score 2):

The body of the MMS is stored in `content://mms/part/`. See [this code](http://www.anddev.org/post42667.html#p42667) for how to read from it, but remember that all of this is undocumented, unsupported and likely to change without notice.

Answer (score -6):

first as you create one screen which you wants to use as the mms screen.
then after as you completed to make it try this under code to send that mms to other person to whom you want.
here you first declare one btn_email button on your project.

btn_email = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_email);

then write the onclickevent on this button which will able to help to send the mms to other person.

send mms code:

btn_email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println("the email button is just pressed..");

```
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                    //Mime type of the attachment (or) u can use sendIntent.setType("*/*")

                    sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");

                    //Subject for the message or Email

                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Picture");

                    //Full Path to the attachment

                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://mnt/"+mUrl));

                    //Use a chooser to decide whether email or mms

                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
                }

            });
```

here is the code which will send the mms to other person form your sdcard path.
this code using the intent code is the android default email sending screen will use.

by this way you are able to send the mms to other person.

now to save the that particulate mms which you have send that other person , as you develop that screen which you have created you just capture that whole screen...and save in sd card like..

e.g:

btn_save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);

```
   btn_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
   {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("the save button is just pressed..");

        saveImageToSD();
        Toast.makeText(Create_Screen_Birthday.this,"Image successfully saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    }

   });
```

protected void saveImageToSD() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    System.out.println("NOW you are on the saveimage to sd card method called block..");

    try
    {
        //String fileName = "myBitmapImage2.png";   
        int  Current_Hour,Current_Minute,Current_Second;
        RelativeLayout settext_relative;

        settext_relative = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.settext_relative);



        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        Current_Hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        Current_Minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        Current_Second = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);


        System.out.println("the value of Current_Year = "+Current_Hour);
        System.out.println("the value of Current_Month = "+Current_Minute);
        System.out.println("the value of Current_Date = "+Current_Second);



        fileName = "Birthday_Card"+"_"+Current_Hour+"_"+Current_Minute+"_"+Current_Second+".png";
        String path = "/sdcard/E-card/Birthday_Cards/";

          newfileName = path + fileName;
         System.out.println("the value of newfilename = "+newfileName);


        System.out.println("The Filename on save card on sdcard = "+fileName);

        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        File file = new File(path);
        file.mkdirs();

        File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);
        outputFile.createNewFile(); 

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(outStream);



         RL.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

     bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( RL.getDrawingCache());

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,bos);

         RL.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();

        btn_preview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        btn_save.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }       

}
```

this above code will save that of screen which you have send then simply you just access or fetch that image from your sdcard  specific path name

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question exactly... I want to create a mms in inbox, should be like: run some code, after that a new entry in the default messaging folder with Inbox/Sent is created.....