# How to restore MMS in Android-2.2?

Tags: android, mms, android-contentprovider, android-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save/Create MMS in inbox Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097319/save-create-mms-in-inbox-android)

**What I want:** I want to restore MMS.

**What I have:** I have restored SMS successfully, that was quiet easy. I am trying to restore MMS using same code/technique by changing the URI etc in SMS code. I think this is not the right way to achieve this task.

**What is the problem:** The problem is that I don't understand the right direction to insert an MMS in my messages DB.

I just, simply, want to create some MMS in my Inbox or Sent folder. Kindly guide me to the right direction or show me some code.