# How to Delete a MMS message from a particular number in Android?

Tags: android, mms

I want to delete a MMS message of a particular phone number in android. How can i do it? 
I am using content://mms-sms/conversations to get list of MMS messaged and tried with the following query:

```
this.getContentResolver().delete(
                Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/" + ThreadId),
                "address=?", new String[] { "contact number" });`
```

But it works only for sms and not for mms. Can someone tell me what can we do to delete particular MMS?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check below detailed Tutorial link for **Read,Write,Delete and update MMS in Android**

[**MMS in Android. Part 2. Working with MMS storage**](http://maximbogatov.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/mms-in-android-part-2-working-with-mms-storage/)

Also Try this

```
Uri msgUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Mms.Inbox.Content_Uri,"1");

SqliteWrapper.delete(this, getContentResolver(), msgUri, null, null); (or) getContentResolver().delete(msguri, null, null);
```

[**Reference**](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/BuQVDm7dTV0)

**Edit:**

here is the method syntax

```
public static Uri withAppendedId (Uri contentUri, long id)
```

and **Uri** is the MMS inbox storage url in content provider

for example SMS Inbox Uri is *"content://sms/inbox"*

also read this page for MMS storage Uri info given here

[**Save/Create MMS in inbox Android**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097319/save-create-mms-in-inbox-android)

Comment: what is Mms in Mms.Inbox.Content_Uri? i am not able to find this class,can you clarify what is it?

Comment: What's the Uri value? check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097319/save-create-mms-in-inbox-android) page for MMS inbox URI

Comment: no this is not correct, did you check the page link I mentioned, just read that it has info what you need, to send mms.